# Transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

I have been trying to find the transfer function of this circuit but I am not getting the right result. it is solved in the textbook but so many steps are skipped.
here is the circuit.

[image]

here are the equations. 
[image]

using the cramer's rule we can obtain TF=I2(s)/(Vs)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you distribute the denominator you have 
$$
\left(R1+Ls\right)\left(R2+Ls+\frac{1}{Cs}\right)-L^2s^2 = R1R2+R1Ls+\frac{R1}{Cs}+R2Ls+L^2s^2+\frac{Ls}{Cs}-L^2s^2 = R1R2+R1Ls+\frac{R1}{Cs}+R2Ls+\frac{L}{C}
$$
mutiplying by Cs we have
$$
R1R2Cs+R1LCs^2+R1+R2LCs^2+Ls
$$
Rearranging
$$
R1LCs^2+R2LCs^2+R1R2Cs+Ls+R1
$$
Combining terms
$$
\left(R1+R2\right)LCs^2+\left(R1R2C+L\right)s+R1
$$